# Regular expression to evaluate string in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a textfield, where a user can write a mathamatical expression which may include if-else block.

So, an expressions can be as follows,

> **a * b**   // here there is space between a and *
>
> **p+q**     // here there is no space between p and +
>
> **x+ y**    // here there is no space between x & + bu there in between + & y
>
> **(x+y)(x*y)**
>
> **if(a>10){a+b}else if(b>10){b-a}else{a+b}**
>
> **if( age>18 ){ a+90 }else{ a-90 }** // spaces may present or not
>
> **if( married == "yes"){ total*0.1 } else{ total*0.2 }** // spaces may present or not

These all above examples are valid expression.

I am trying to validate all these types of expression with single regular expression.
How a regular expression look like in JavaScript?

Thank you :)

Comment: What did you tried? What about nested if-else block?

Comment: Could not proceed as not much aware of regx. Yes, there is nested if else also.

Comment: it's too hard to do with regex.

Comment: A regex is not even close to the proper tool for parsing Javascript language syntax and certainly isn't the most readable or maintainable method either.

Comment: You should probably write your own parser (or at least the rules for one)]. You can use http://pegjs.majda.cz/ to generate one for you.

Comment: since the expressions are all valid JS, it sounds like you need eval() (a built-in parser)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this with regular expressions. The main problem is that you cannot check that arbitrary levels of nested parentheses, brackets, braces, etc. are balanced. (See the answers to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns) for more info.)

Handling optional white space is easy in a regex; just use `\s*` every place that optional white space is allowed and use `\s+` wherever white space is required (e.g., to separate words—such as `else\s+if`, where there must be at least one and possibly more white space characters between the "else" and the "if").